# Ubuntu 20.04 hangs on shutdown / reboot

Tags: 20.04, reboot

I did an install of Ubuntu 20.04.
cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.13.0-37-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-111) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 15:44:28 UTC 2022

Shutdown and reboot hangs on the Ubuntu splash screen.

[image]

Comment: I'd apply all upgrades and re-try. You're using an *unsupported* kernel, so looking for fixes makes little sense to be (*if kernel related*) until you've moved to a *supported* kernel, ie. using the GA kernel (5.4) or HWE kernel (5.15) where I'd try again. Have you applied all security fixes? as your details imply you haven't or you're not using Ubuntu at all (*but a Ubuntu based system*)